# Accessing the key/value of a dictionary

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

How do  I access the key/value of a dictionary? I  have this code:

```
    Try


        If keystrokeDictionary.ContainsKey(letter) Then
            keystrokeDictionary.Keys.Equals(letter)
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    Return letter
```

`Letter` is a single letter that gets passed in with just its string value. Then `keystrokedictionary` is a dictionary that the information looks like this:

```
{[65, 0]}
{[66, 1]}
{[67, 2]}
```

Where the key is the first number and the value is the second number. Since my code isn't looking at the key/value right, it's not returning a letter, and therefore not working.

Comment: It's not clear, from your question, what exactly you are trying to do.  What is the meaning of the key and value in the dictionary?  What is the meaning of the `letter` variable, and what is the meaning of the return value?

Comment: I'm doing virtual clicks, and you need to use bytes in order to do that (from what I understand, although i could be wrong) So I'm trying to convert the string to its corresponding byte value by using a dictionary

Comment: The corresponding byte value using which encoding?  ASCII?  What is the purpose of the dictionary?  To store the mapping between character byte values and what?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure if the dictionary is the best way to go, but then I need to find out another way to convert it to ASCII byte form...

Comment: I still don't understand what you want to convert.  Convert from what to what?  In your example, you show the dictionary containing a key of 65 and a value of 0.  So what is that?  What is the meaning of 65 and what is the meaning of 0?  What is the name of this function?  What are it's parameters and expected return value?

Comment: Have you tried using an array instead of a dictionary?

Answer (score 5):

Try like this,Use item to get corresponding value

```
letter = " ";

If keystrokeDictionary.ContainsKey(letter) Then
letter = keystrokeDictionary.Item(letter)
End If

Return letter
```

Answer (score 4):

`.Equals()` is not an assignment operator, but a comparison function.

Try

```
letter = " ";

If keystrokeDictionary.ContainsKey(letter) Then
   letter = keystrokeDictionary.Values(letter)
End If

Return letter
```

Comment: There is no `keystrokeDictionary.Value` it's coming up as `keystrokeDictionary.Values`

Comment: @bbesase Sorry:  I was doing that from memory and screwed it up.  I've updated my example.    TryGetValue() is more efficient, so if you're hitting the dictionary hard, you might want to try that approach.