# VB Net: Getting value by key from array of dictionaries

Tags: arrays, vb.net, dictionary

I got an Array of dictionaries (Of string, string) like following:

["First":"One", "Second":"Two"]

How to get "One" via "First"?

I tried getting via Key but Array does not support key (which makes sense)

Additional info: The input is a deserialized json:

```
{"First" : "One",
"Second" : "Two"}
```

Comment: Use `ContainsKey()` and then `Values` property to obtain the value. Similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17817538/accessing-the-key-value-of-a-dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by an array of dictionaries.You should use a dictionary instead. Like this

```
 Dim dictionary1 As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
 dictionary1.Add("First", "One")
 dictionary1.Add("Second" , "Two")
```

To access the dictionary entries, use

```
Dim pair As KeyValuePair(Of String, String)
For Each pair In dictionary1
   If  pair.key = "First" Then
    'Eg Label1.Text = pair.value or Console.WriteLine(pair.value)
   End If
Next
```

Answer (score -1):

`IF myDict.ContainsKey("First") Then
     Dim First = dictionaryList("First")
 End If`